# A generic terminology for left and right parts - i.e. M and N - of a general lambda application term MN?

Tags: terminology, type-theory

As pointed out in the comments, the rhs and lhs are both terms, so "rhs term" and "lhs term" works. There may be a more evocative, and equally concise term.

Presumably (?) the only important role of the lhs is as a "substitution scope" for the rhs term. So the rhs term of an application might be the "argument" of the application and the lhs it's "scope". Note: lhs term need not generally be an abstraction (it might be a variable).

A subset of application terms - those with lhs an abstraction - are so called $\beta-redex$'s.

Comment: They are [terms](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/#Syn)

Comment: I'm wary of posts that rely entirely on the title to state a question.  While you might be able to do so in this case, what suffers is the *context* of your problem.  You may have in mind a formal language of some kind, but Readers will have to guess at your intended application of "terminology".  Of course the context is well known to you, but not to us.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks!

Comment: @hardmath sorry this question lacks a grand context. It is about a concise (pedantic) ways to refer to the stated terms. Perhaps too trivial for here? I can always use my prefered terms argument and scope in my thinking and writing, but maybe there are more evocative or conventional names out there, given how fundamental application is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a $\lambda$-calculus, an expression of the form $M\,N$ is called an *application*, where $M$ is the *applicand* and $N$ is the *argument*. These terms appear in most texts on the $\lambda$-calculus (though "applicand" is not as common as the other two). See, for instance, the Wikipedia article on [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Summary_of_lambda_calculus).

Comment: Thanks! Do you see anything problems with adopting "scope" instead of applicand?

Comment: "Scope" has a preexisting meaning, referring to the subterms in which a particular variable binding holds, i.e. when the use of that variable is well-formed. So it may be misleading to some readers to reuse this word for another (somewhat related) meaning.

Comment: I think my sense of "scope" and that sense you talk of are identical only in the special case of -redex terms (which in my references so far are defined as application terms with the lhs an abstraction).